# Index of / error while installing WP

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, indexing, upload

I just uploaded word press on my host. created database successfully. but when I brows my site as www.kiaradgroups.com I receive index of / page !

how can I solve this problem so that I continue installing my word press.

EDIT=======================
I changed settings to no indexing in index part of host.

I also edited .htaccess as bellow:
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

but still having the problem

===============================

[image]

Comment: Thats not enough information for us to help - we're not mind readers,  we don't know whats wrong if you don't show us the relevant code or settings! Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: getting this means that your site is empty so no file .. make sure your correctly added your domain, maybe it's and addon domain in a subfolder and not the root. Can you give us the name of your hosting provide ? and describe how you upload the files ?

Comment: i uploaded wordpress to public_html and extracted it. created database and edited wp-config.php and added database informations to it. I used upload manager of host not ftp. also changed INDEXING to no indexing and edited ,htaccess too ! but problem still remains !